# ActionBar Sherlock tab too short // How to set width of an tab

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I'm working on a project with a tab navigation. Because it should be compatible with Gingerbread I'm using Actionbar Sherlock for this approach. My Problem is that one tab is too short an one letter of the word is shown in a second line:
[image]

What can I do to set the width of an tab so that it fits the word?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: The quick and easy way would probably be to give it a point where you'd rather want it to cut off the word, as in `mit-glieder`...?

Comment: But that would still result in a two-lined tab, wouldn't it? I want to achieve only one line for every tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce font size in tabs to make it according to your needs, but his solution has its limits.

One of other solution is that, you can use ViewPagerIndicator library, It has tabs, which can scroll if they do not fit in screen. See example code from following link

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator